# How to pass id in controller from view (Edit user in laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

I have a view which  displays all the `user` records in database. When click on the `edit` button it shows an error:

> Missing required parameters for [Route: admin.] [URI: admin/edit/{id}].

```
{!! Form::open(array('action' => 'Admin\AdminController@edit')) !!} 

<tbody>
   @unless (empty($userdata))
   @foreach ($userdata as $user)
   <tr>
      <td>{{$user->id}}</td>
      <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
      <td>{{ date('d-m-Y', strtotime($user->created_at)) }}</td>
      <td>{{$user->email}}</td>
      <td>{{$user->role}}</td>
      <td><a href="admin/edit/{{$user->id}}" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a></td>
   </tr>
   @endforeach 
   @endunless                                                 
</tbody>
```

routes.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth','admin'], 'prefix' => 'admin', 'as' => 'admin.'], function () {
    Route::get('/home', 'Admin\AdminController@index');    
    Route::get('/register', 'Admin\AdminController@register');
    Route::post('/create', 'Admin\AdminController@create');
    Route::get('/manage', 'Admin\AdminController@manage');
    Route::any('/quote', 'Quote\QuoteController@index');
    Route::patch('/edit/{id}', 'Admin\AdminController@edit');
});
```

I tried these also but still not working.

route():

```
<td><a href="{{ route('admin.edit', ['id'=>$user->id]) }}" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a></td>
```

url():

```
<td><a href="{{ url('/admin/edit/'.$user->id) }}" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a></td>
```

Comment: can you show your complete route

Comment: Iuuse is fixed: There was conflict with form action controller and anchor route both request hitting to same controller which was the issue. 

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{!! Form::open(array('action' => 'Admin\AdminController@edit')) !!}
```

Issue Fixed: There was issue with my form action which was pointing to same controller method.

```
<div class="box-body table-responsive">
   <table class="table table-hover data-table">
      <thead>
         <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Role</th>
            <th>Edit</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         @unless (empty($userdata))
         @foreach ($userdata as $user)
         <tr>
            <td>{{$user->id}}</td>
            <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
            <td>{{ date('d-m-Y', strtotime($user->created_at)) }}</td>
            <td>{{$user->email}}</td>
            <td><a href="{{ url('/admin/edit/'.$user->id) }}" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a></td>
         </tr>
         @endforeach 
         @endunless                                                 
      </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

Routes

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth','admin'], 'prefix' => 'admin', 'as' => 'admin.'], function () {
    Route::get('/home', 'Admin\AdminController@index');    
    Route::get('/register', 'Admin\AdminController@register');
    Route::post('/create', 'Admin\AdminController@create');
    Route::get('/manage', 'Admin\AdminController@manage');
    Route::any('/quote', 'Quote\QuoteController@index');    
    #Route::post('/edit', ['uses'=>'Admin\AdminController@edit']);


    Route::get('edit/{id}', 'Admin\AdminController@edit')->name('update.request');

});
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
<td>
    <a href="/edit/{{$user->id}}" class="btn btn-primary">
        <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
    </a>
</td>
```

to:

```
<td>
    <a href="/admin/edit/{{$user->id}}" class="btn btn-primary">
        <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
    </a>
</td>
```

Your route should include `admin`.

Comment: can you show your userData as I think for some data id is null

Answer (score 2):

You can pass it through `URL`.

If its a **form**, you can have a hidden input for the `id`. E.g.

```
<input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{ $user->id }}">
```

Answer (score 1):

i think you need add get route for edit

```
Route::patch('/edit/{id}', 'Admin\AdminController@edit')->name('edit');
```

and add route function in blade

```
<td><a href="{{ route('admin.edit', ['id'=>$user->id]) }}" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a></td>
```

Comment: I have tried both route() and url() methods but it's not working

Comment: Did you add name to route? Show your route and blade.