# Trying to pull data entered into one form to a new form for a separate action

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am working on my final year project, a scheduling sugery management system, I have already created a request form to request a surgery to be booked, entries to this form are then displayed on a waiting list view. I would ideally like to be able to click one of the data entries on the waiting list to be able to 'create a booking', when an entry is clicked in the waiting list it should take you to another form similar to the surgery request form, but with the data already entered into the field, on this form, I then want to be able to submit it, then view the submitted bookingson a 'booked surgeries' view, I was wondering if anyone has any suggestions on my best way to go about this without affecting affecting the entries of the waiting list.

**Below is the code for my surgery request form view:**

```
'''
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<h1>Surgery Request Form</h1>
{!! Form::open(['url' => 'requestform/submit']) !!}

    <div class="form-group">
    {{Form::label('requestID', 'Request ID')}}
    {{Form::number('requestID', 'Request ID', ['class' => 'form-control',])}}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    {{Form::label('requestDate', 'Request Date')}}
    {{Form::date('requestDate', \Carbon\Carbon::now(), ['class' => 'form-control'])}}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    {{Form::label('patientID', 'Patient ID')}}
    {{Form::number('patientID', 'Patient ID', ['class' => 'form-control'])}}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    {{Form::label('patientForename', 'Patient Forename')}}
    {{Form::text('patientForename', 'Patient Forename', ['class' => 'form-control'])}}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    {{Form::label('patientSurname', 'Patient Surname')}}
    {{Form::text('patientSurname', 'Patient Surname', ['class' => 'form-control',])}}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    {{Form::label('patientSex', 'Patient Sex')}}
    {{Form::select('patientSex', ['Male' => 'Male', 'Female' => 'Female'], null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => ''])}}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    {{Form::label('patientDOB', 'Patient DOB')}}
    {{Form::date('patientDOB')}}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    {{Form::label('surgeryType', 'Surgery Type')}}
    {{Form::select('surgeryType', ['Appendectomy' => 'Appendectomy', 'Myringotomy' => 'Myringotomy', 'Tonsillectomy' => 'Tonsillectomy', 'Hysteroscopy' => 'Hysteroscopy', 'Cystoscopy' => 'Cystoscopy',
    'Hysterectomy' => 'Hysterectomy', 'Cholecystectomy' => 'Cholecystectomy'], null, ['class' => 'form-control','placeholder' => ''])}}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    {{Form::label('patientUrgency', 'Patient Urgency')}}
    {{Form::select('patientUrgency', ['Routine' => 'Routine', 'Urgent' => 'Urgent', 'Red-Flag' => 'Red-Flag'], null, ['class' => 'form-control','placeholder' => ''])}}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    {{Form::label('bloodGroup', 'Blood Group')}}
    {{Form::select('bloodGroup', ['A' => 'A', 'B' => 'B', 'O' => 'O', 'AB' => 'AB'], null, ['class' => 'form-control','placeholder' => ''])}}
    </div>

    <div>
      {{Form::submit('Submit Request', ['class'=> 'btn btn-primary'])}}
    </div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
@endsection
```

'''

**Below is the controller code for the surgery request form:**

```
        <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\RequestForm;

class RequestFormsController extends Controller
{
    public function submit(Request $request){
      $this->validate($request, [
        'requestID' => 'required',
        'requestDate' => 'required',
        'patientID' => 'required',
        'patientForename' => 'required',
        'patientSurname'=> 'required',
        'patientSex' => 'required',
        'patientDOB' => 'required',
        'surgeryType' => 'required',
        'patientUrgency' => 'required',
        'bloodGroup' => 'required'
      ]);


      // Create new Request Form
      $requestForm = new RequestForm;
      $requestForm->requestID = $request->input('requestID');
      $requestForm->requestDate = $request->input('requestDate');
      $requestForm->patientID = $request->input('patientID');
      $requestForm->patientForename = $request->input('patientForename');
      $requestForm->patientSurname = $request->input('patientSurname');
      $requestForm->patientSex = $request->input('patientSex');
      $requestForm->patientDOB = $request->input('patientDOB');
      $requestForm->surgeryType = $request->input('surgeryType');
      $requestForm->patientUrgency = $request->input('patientUrgency');
      $requestForm->bloodGroup = $request->input('bloodGroup');

      //Save Request form

      $requestForm->save();

      //redirect

      return redirect('/')->with('success', 'Request Submitted');
    }

return redirect('/')->with('success', 'Request Submitted');

public function submitBooking(Booking $Booking){
      $this->validate($booking, [
        'requestID' => 'required',
        'requestDate' => 'required',
        'patientID' => 'required',
        'bookingID' => 'required',
        'patientForename' => 'required',
        'patientSurname'=> 'required',
        'patientSex' => 'required',
        'patientDOB' => 'required',
        'surgeryDate' => 'required',
        'surgeryType' => 'required',
        'theatreRoomID' => 'required',
        'patientUrgency' => 'required',
        'patientNotes' => 'required',
        'bloodGroup' => 'required'
      ]);


      // Create new Request Form
      $bookingForm = new bookingForm;
      $bookingForm->requestID = $booking->input('requestID');
      $bookingForm->requestDate = $booking->input('requestDate');
      $bookingForm->bookingID = $booking->input('bookingID');
      $bookingForm->patientID = $booking->input('patientID');
      $bookingForm->patientForename = $booking->input('patientForename');
      $bookingForm->patientSurname = $booking->input('patientSurname');
      $bookingForm->patientSex = $booking->input('patientSex');
      $bookingForm->patientDOB = $booking->input('patientDOB');
      $bookingForm->surgeryType = $booking->input('surgeryType');
      $bookingForm->surgeryDate = $booking->input('surgeryDate');
      $bookingForm->patientUrgency = $booking->input('patientUrgency');
      $bookingForm->patientNotes = $booking->input('patientNotes');
      $bookingForm->bloodGroup = $booking->input('bloodGroup');

      //Save Booking form

      $bookingForm->save();

      //redirect
      return redirect('/')->with('success', 'Booking Submitted');

    public function getWaitingLists(){
      $waitinglists = RequestForm::all();

      return view('waitinglist')->with('waitinglist', $waitinglists);
    }

    public function getPatientData(Request $request,$id){
 $patientDetail = RequestForm::where('patientID',$id)->first();

 return view('bookingFormView')->with('patientDetail', $patientDetail);
}


}
```

**And below is the waiting list view code:**

```
     @extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<h1>Waiting List</h1>
@if(count($waitinglist) > 0)
  @foreach($waitinglist as $requestForm)
  <a href="http://localhost:8000/bookingForm/show/{{$requestForm->patientID}}"><td>{{$requestForm->patientID}}</td></a>
    <table class="table">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">Request ID</th>

      <th scope="col">Request Date</th>
      <th scope="col">Patient ID</th>
      <th scope="col">Patient Forename</th>
      <th scope="col">Patient Surname</th>
      <th scope="col">Patient Sex</th>
      <th scope="col">Patient DOB</th>
      <th scope="col">Surgery Type</th>
      <th scope="col">Patient Urgeny</th>
      <th scope="col">Blood Group</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"></th>
      <td>{{$requestForm->requestID}}</td>
      <td>{{$requestForm->requestDate}}</td>
      <td>{{$requestForm->patientID}}</td>
      <td>{{$requestForm->patientForename}}</td>
      <td>{{$requestForm->patientSurname}}</td>
      <td>{{$requestForm->patientSex}}</td>
      <td>{{$requestForm->patientDOB}}</td>
      <td>{{$requestForm->surgeryType}}</td>
      <td>{{$requestForm->patientUrgency}}</td>
      <td>{{$requestForm->bloodGroup}}</</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
  @endforeach
@endif
@endsection

@section('sidebar')
@parent
<p>This is appended to the Sidebar</p>
@endsection
```

**Routes (web.php)**

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/
Route::get('/requestform', 'PagesController@getRequestForm');

Route::get('/waitinglist', 'RequestFormsController@getWaitingLists');


Route::post('/requestform/submit', 'RequestFormsController@submit');

Route::get('/bookingForm/show/{patientID}', 'RequestFormsController@getPatientData' )->name('update.request');


Route::get('/', 'PagesController@getHome');

Route::get('/about', 'PagesController@getAbout');

Route::get('/contact', 'PagesController@getContact');

Route::get('/welcome', 'PagesController@getWelcome');

Route::get('/login', 'LoginController@getLogin');

Route::get('/messages', 'MessagesController@getMessages');

Route::post('/contact/submit', 'MessagesController@submit');

Route::get('/register', 'RegisterController@getRegister');

Route::get('/logout', 'LoginController@logout');

Route::get('/logout', '\App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout');


Auth::routes();
Route::get('/', 'PagesController@getHome');
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');

  Route::prefix('admin')->group(function() {
    Route::get('/login', 'Auth\AdminLoginController@showLoginForm')->name('admin.login');
    Route::post('/login', 'Auth\AdminLoginController@login')->name('admin.login.submit');
    Route::get('/', 'AdminController@index')->name('admin.dashboard');
  });
```

**Routes (PagesController)**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PagesController extends Controller
{
    public function getHome(){
      return view('home');
    }

    public function getAbout(){
      return view('about');
    }

    public function getContact(){
      return view('Contact');
    }

    public function getLogin(){
      return view('login');
    }

    public function getWelcome(){
      return view('welcome');
    }

    public function getRegister(){
      return view('register');
    }

    public function getAdmin(){
      return view('admin');
    }

    public function getRequestForm(){
      return view('requestForm');
    }

    public function getPatientData(){
      return view('bookingForm');
    }






}
```

Booking Form View:

```
    @extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<h1>Booking Form</h1>
{!! Form::open(['url' => 'bookingform/submit']) !!}

    <div class="form-group">
    {{Form::label('requestID', 'Request ID')}}
    {{Form::number('requestID', $patientDetail->requestID, ['class' => 'form-control',])}}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    {{Form::label('requestDate', 'Request Date')}}
    {{Form::date('requestDate', $patientDetail->requestDate, ['class' => 'form-control'])}}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    {{Form::label('patientID', 'Patient ID')}}
    {{Form::number('patientID', $patientDetail->patientID, ['class' => 'form-control'])}}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    {{Form::label('patientForename', 'Patient Forename')}}
    {{Form::text('patientForename', $patientDetail->patientForename, ['class' => 'form-control'])}}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    {{Form::label('patientSurname', 'Patient Surname')}}
    {{Form::text('patientSurname', $patientDetail->patientSurname, ['class' => 'form-control',])}}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    {{Form::label('patientSex', 'Patient Sex')}}
    {{Form::label('patientSex', $patientDetail->patientSex, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => ''])}}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    {{Form::label('patientDOB', 'Patient DOB')}}
    {{Form::label('patientDOB', $patientDetail->patientDOB, ['class' => 'form-control','placeholder' => ''])}}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    {{Form::label('surgeryType', 'Surgery Type')}}
    {{Form::label('surgeryType', $patientDetail->surgeryType, ['class' => 'form-control','placeholder' => ''])}}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    {{Form::label('patientUrgency', 'Patient Urgency')}}
    {{Form::label('patientUrgency', $patientDetail->patientUrgency, ['class' => 'form-control','placeholder' => ''])}}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    {{Form::label('bloodGroup', 'Blood Group')}}
    {{Form::label('bloodGroup', $patientDetail->bloodGroup,  ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => ''])}}
    </div>

    <div>
      {{Form::submit('Submit Booking', ['class'=> 'btn btn-primary'])}}
    </div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
@endsection
```

Any help for this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can give a href link with the RequestForm id and write a function which returns whole data of current RequestForm id and pass the data to your booked surgeries' view and pass the data as default value in your `{{Form::text('patientSurname', 'Patient Surname'}}`
you can add this to your view where you are showing the patientId just wrap that  with and anchor tag :

```
@extends('layouts.app')
  @section('content')
 <h1>Waiting List</h1>
 @if(count($waitinglist) > 0)
  @foreach($waitinglist as $requestForm)
   <table class="table">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
     <th scope="col">#</th>
     <th scope="col">Request ID</th>

  <th scope="col">Request Date</th>
  <th scope="col">Patient ID</th>
  <th scope="col">Patient Forename</th>
  <th scope="col">Patient Surname</th>
  <th scope="col">Patient Sex</th>
  <th scope="col">Patient DOB</th>
  <th scope="col">Surgery Type</th>
  <th scope="col">Patient Urgeny</th>
  <th scope="col">Blood Group</th>
</tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
<tr>
  <th scope="row"></th>
  <td><a href={{ url('/bookingForm/show/'.$requestForm->patientID) }}>{{$requestForm->patientID}}</a></td>
  <td>{{$requestForm->requestDate}}</td>
  <td>{{$requestForm->patientID}}</td>
  <td>{{$requestForm->patientForename}}</td>
  <td>{{$requestForm->patientSurname}}</td>
  <td>{{$requestForm->patientSex}}</td>
  <td>{{$requestForm->patientDOB}}</td>
  <td>{{$requestForm->surgeryType}}</td>
  <td>{{$requestForm->patientUrgency}}</td>
  <td>{{$requestForm->bloodGroup}}</</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
 </table>
 @endforeach
 @endif
 @endsection

@section('sidebar')
@parent
 <p>This is appended to the Sidebar</p>
@endsection
```

if you wanna know more about anchor tag [click here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp) and then in your controller you can write a function :

```
  public function getPatientData(Request $request,$id){
  $patientDetail = RequestForm::where('patientID',$id)->first();

  return view('bookingFormView')->with('patientDetail', $patientDetail);
}
```

and finally you will get the data in bookingFormView attach it with your form as the default value of element and you are good to go

Comment: Would this affect the entries already in the database from the Request booking form?

Comment: I forgot to add, I'm unsure how to make the waiting list entries clickable to take you to the booking form, I want to be able to use the details already in the waiting list entries and add to them them as a separate entry in a separate form if that makes sense?

Comment: yes this makes sense can you please correct the waiting list view code that's controller written over there please show me your waiting list view code i'll suggest what to add

Comment: Apologies that was a silly mistake of mine, I have updated the code of the waiting list view now!

Comment: I had made the changes please take a look

Comment: Sorry for being a pest about this, but do I add the controller function to the RequestForms Controller or make a new BookingForms Controller? Then add the href link into a new view called bookingFormView?

Comment: the href is for your waiting list view code then you can write new function in same controller or you can make a new one what I suggest is you write it into the same controller and then to the bookingform view .... put the php code i've mentioned in your controller and html code in your waiting list view code

Comment: I have added the href into my waiting list view code and the php code into my controller but when I click an entry in the waiting list when running my website im getting a localhost error saying it refused to connect, am i still missing something? Sorry for being a pest again

Comment: can you put your new code here It'll be more easy then

Comment: I've updated the code now! I really appreciate your help by the way! Quite new to this still

Comment: i've updated my answer with your waiting list view file please take a look also you can see a implementation here with the problem you have https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52739424/how-to-pass-id-in-controller-from-view-edit-user-in-laravel

Comment: Hi there, sorry this issue is still ongoing, I am still having an issue when trying to display the data on the bookingFormView, do I need to include something in a bookingFormView view? I had a look at that link you suggested but unfortunately haven't gottrn any further! It is returning a blank screen at the moment unfortunately, no errors just a white screen.

Comment: Forgot to add, I have also edited my original question to show my routes files incase this is where my issue is arising!

Comment: Sorry for the multiple comments in a short time, wanted to update you incase you respond to a previous question, I now have it so that the booking form displays the current entry details from the waiting list (I have added this code above), is there a way I can add theatre room and performing surgeon fields to the booking form, then submit the booking form to a bookingForm table that won't affect the waiting list entries? Many thanks again and apologies for the inconvenience.

Comment: you can submit your form to the bookingForm/submit route and make a entry in bookingForm table that won't affect your waiting list table

Comment: Ok thank you! What would be my best way of making the entry in the booking form table? How would I go about directing the data into it? I tested hitting submit but at present it just brings back all of my validation errors such as 'Please enter Patient ID'.

Comment: Ok so it turns out the valiation errors where because I had changed the entries being displayed on the bookingForm that came from the waiting list, to be displayed as read only, but I changed this to make them read/write but when I click submit I am getting an error to say " Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'", I assume this is because it is trying to submit to the requestForms table rather than the new bookingForm table? Sorry to keep firing questions to you on this issue, I really am appreciating all of your help!

Comment: yes you gotta write one more function in your controller to save your booking details you can't use same waiting list table also never try to set a value for your primary key that is table_name.id let it be auto incremented ... if this is your college project you take help from your prof. as these are the basic things

Comment: Unfortunately this is solo project and my supervisor isn't from a coding background so I've been left on my own to figure it out :( you habe been an absolute lifesaver!! I will have a go at writing the function into my controller and let you know if I get it working :)

Comment: Hi again, I have edited the controller code above, would you recommend doing the function to submit the booking as I have displayed above or am I on the completely wrong lines altogether?

Comment: this would work ... only just above submitBooking function you've written an extra return that can cause you error

Comment: Im getting an error saying: 
Class App\Http\Controllers\Booking does not exist, any idea what might be causing this?